# Binary file reading, convert 2 bytes to an unsigned short C

Tags: c, binary, unsigned, short

I have a problem with reading 2 bytes at onces and convert it to an unsigned short, big endian.

This is my current code, I want to print the unsigned short big endian as well, and it should be the number 25.

So this code is for reading a binary file, I saved all the files to a buffer, and I need buffer[5] and buffer[6] to the unsigned short, big endian

```
void read_binair(const char* filename)
    {
        FILE *file;
        char *buffer;
        unsigned long fileLen;
        int i;
        char character;
        Level* level = level_alloc_empty();

        file = fopen(filename, "rb");
        if (!file)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", filename);
            return;
        }



        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        fileLen = ftell(file);
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);


        buffer = (char *)malloc(fileLen + 1);
        if (!buffer)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
            fclose(file);
            return;
        }



        fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, file);
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        {   
            printf("%c", (char) buffer[i]);
        }
        i = buffer[4];
        printf("%d", i);
        //read buffer[5] and buffer[6] together as a unsigned short, big endian
        fclose(file);
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the `<<` and `|` operators?

Comment: I think we need @unwind. This guy is casting the return value of malloc.

Comment: @PeterSchneider While @unwind is not here: Please do not cast the result of `malloc()`. Doing so is useless and can hide errors.

Comment: @FUZxxl Ha! Caught one! Poe's law still works!

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, since you don't mention the endianess in which numbers were stored in the file nor the endianess of the processor. It is impossible to answer the question without knowing those 2 things. (Amazingly, people still try to answer...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will create an `unsigned short` from `buffer` in big endian:

```
unsigned short us = (buffer[5] << 8) | buffer[6];
```

Comment: @Jongware LSB is on `buffer[6]`, it's big endian.

Comment: I may be dense but is something wrong with the code? Should we assume that the data comes in as little endian and we want to convert it, i.e. do a `ntohs()` on it? The OP was not very specific.

Comment: Why does endianness of the machine affect the code here? Assuming that the actual 16 bit number is 0xF1E4 and `buffer[5] = 0xE4` and `buffer[6] = 0xF1`, how does `(buffer[5] << 8) | buffer[6];` make sense?

Comment: @work.bin, You are right, endianness will not going to be affected by machine.

Comment: This code will have problems should `buffer[6] < 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming -

1. you are using a compiler which supports C99, and
2. the data in the file is in network byte order

You need -

```
uint16_t half_word = ((uint8_t)buffer[5] << 8) | ((uint8_t)buffer[6])
```

P.S. -

- Use `uint8_t *buffer` instead of `char *buffer` to obviate the need for typecasting buffer octets.

  - See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html
- If you are using C89/90 -

  - `typedef unsigned char uint8_t;`
  - `typedef unsigned short int uint16_t;`